# limit of $\sqrt{12n+20}-\sqrt{12n}$

Tags: calculus

Compute the following:

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{12n+20}-\sqrt{12n}$

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+2n}$

In both I wasn't able to find anything. I tried $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}$ for the first one. And I was able to show second one converge but i need the actual value.

Comment: Why not simplify and extract the factor of $4$ from each term?

Comment: For the first multiply and divide by $\sqrt{12n+20}+\sqrt{12n}$. For the second write $\frac{1}{n^2+2n}=\frac{1/2}{n}-\frac{1/2}{n+2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first one multiply and divide by $$ \sqrt {12n+20} +\sqrt {12n}$$

For the second one use partial fraction $$\frac {1}{n^2+2n} = (1/2)[(1/n) -1/{(n+2)}]$$

and you get a telescoping series.

You should be able to handle both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by the conjugate on top/bottom to get:

$$\frac{12n+20-12n}{\sqrt{12n+20}+\sqrt{12n}}.$$

Can you finish the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach for the limit:

Using that for $x>0$,$y\ge -x$
$$\sqrt{x+y}=\sqrt{\left(\sqrt x+\frac y{2\sqrt x}\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{4x}}\le\sqrt x+\frac y{2\sqrt x},$$

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{12n+20}-\sqrt{12n})\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{12n}+\frac{10}{\sqrt{12 n}}-\sqrt{12n}\right)=0$$

Answer (score -3):

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt{12 n + 20} - \sqrt{12 n} \right)$$

$$= 2 \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt{3 n + 5} - \sqrt{3 n} \right)$$

$$= 2 \lim\limits_{n^\prime \to \infty} \left( \sqrt{n^\prime + 5} - \sqrt{n^\prime} \right)$$

Proof:  For any $0<\epsilon$ we can find an $n$ such that the left-hand side is less than $\epsilon$:

$$\frac{5-\epsilon^2}{2 \epsilon} < \sqrt{n}$$.

Thus the limit is $0$.

Comment: ........(Proof?)